# How to Display Paging Without PageNumber using PagedList MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I'm trying to display page without page number using `PagedList.MVC`, so there are only first, previous, next, and last links.

I try to set `MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 0` but there is ... ... between previous and next links, like in this picture below:

[image]

How to configure the `PagedList.MVC` so that I can get only first, previous, next, and last links?

[image]

Comment: you can hide them via css

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how to do this via css?

Comment: this may help you: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList#custom-pager-configurations